# Updating data.frame from another data.frame with different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merging-data

Given two data frames

```
old.df = data.frame(SampleNo=c('A1', 'B4', 'C5', 'D4'), Result=c(rep("Successful",4)), NoUnit = c(rep(4,4)))
new.df = data.frame(SampleNo=c('A1', 'C5', 'D4', 'E4'), Result=c(rep("Successful",2),rep( "Failure",2)),State=c(rep("California",2),rep("New York",2)))
```

such that it has the following format:

```
> old.df
  SampleNo     Result      NoUnit
1       A1     Successful      4
2       B4     Successful      4
3       C5     Successful      4
4       D4     Successful      4


> new.df
  SampleNo     Result      State
1       A1 Successful California
2       C5 Successful California
3       D4    Failure   New York
4       E4    Failure   New York
```

I would like to update contents of old.df with new data from new.df maintaining the row succession of old.df and adding new columns from new.df. The resulting data.frame would be:

```
 SampleNo     Result   NoUnit      State
1       A1 Successful      4 California
2       B4 Successful      4       <NA>
3       C5 Successful      4 California
4       D4    Failure      4   New York
5       E4    Failure     NA   New York
```

Answer (score 3):

```
merge(old.df,new.df,all=TRUE)

  SampleNo     Result NoUnit      State
1       A1 Successful      4 California
2       B4 Successful      4       <NA>
3       C5 Successful      4 California
4       D4    Failure      4   New York
5       E4    Failure     NA   New York
```

**Edit after the rules were changed by OP:**

```
df <- merge(old.df,new.df,all=TRUE,by="SampleNo")
df$Result <- with(df,factor(ifelse(is.na(Result.y),
                             as.character(Result.x),as.character(Result.y))))
df$Result.x <- NULL; df$Result.y <- NULL

  SampleNo NoUnit      State     Result
1       A1      4 California Successful
2       B4      4       <NA> Successful
3       C5      4 California Successful
4       D4      4   New York    Failure
5       E4     NA   New York    Failure
```

Comment: I checked the answer too soon. The old.df was supposed to be all "Successful". This answer is wrong as you get two D4's.

Answer (score 1):

Merge won't do this by itself.  But you don't really want to merge on the `"Result"` column, only on the `"SampleNo"` column, then combine the `"Result"` values, using new values if available, otherwise old values.

Here is some code that does that, for all columns in the intersection other than `"SampleNo"`

```
merge.by.sample <- function(old.df, new.df, by='SampleNo') {
  r <- merge(old.df, new.df,all=T,by=by)

  merge.col <- function(r, col) {
    xname <- paste0(col, '.x')
    yname <- paste0(col, '.y')

    r[col] <- factor(r[,yname], levels=union(levels(r[,xname]), levels(r[,yname])))
    r[col][is.na(r[col])] <- r[xname][is.na(r[col])]
    r[!(names(r) %in% c(xname, yname))]
  }

  i <- intersect(names(old.df), names(new.df))
  i <- i[!i %in% by]

  for (col in i) {
    r <- merge.col(r, col)
  }
  r
}
```

Comment: This might work on a small dataset like above but if I have to deal with >100 columns then this would become too 'tasky'. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: A function can be created to do this, then it can be applied to each desired column.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: its not possible to do this: factor(r[yname])